# Is there a free version of the Lucida Bright fonts out there?

Tags: fonts, calligraphy, lucida

Or, failing that, do you happen to know whom one might purchase them from?

Thanks in advance for you knowledgeable replies.

Comment: Why is  hard to believe? Artists need to eat too.

Comment: No, there is none.

Comment: See it: http://www.fontesgratis.com.br/l/Lucida-Bright.php

Comment: See https://www.tug.org/store/lucida/ for purchasing the fonts.